# Spring keystore bean

Tags: java, spring, keystore

In spring.application I've specified keystore name and password.
I'd like to sign some data with Signature.sign() from java security, but to do that I'd need Keystore. Is there a way to get Spring managed keystore bean, or do I have to create my own keystore, even when it's already used by spring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the

```
@Autowired
private KeyStore keyStore;
```

if you've configured it correctly in your XML/Java configuration like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:crypt="http://springcryptoutils.com/schema/crypt"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
                       http://springcryptoutils.com/schema/crypt http://springcryptoutils.com/schema/crypt.xsd">

    <crypt:keystore id="keystore"
                location="somePath}"
                password="somePassword"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: any way to configure this with annotations/java?

Comment: Should be something like this:
      @Bean
    public KeyStore keyStore() throws IOException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(new ClassPathResource("path").getInputStream(), "password".toCharArray());
        return keyStore;
    }
I'm not entirely sure about the ClassPathResource but that should be easy to find out :)

Comment: yea, I implented this, it works, although I was hoping for out-of-box. Anyway, thank you much, approved. If you add this to answer - perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 2.4.x:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

@Configuration
public class KeyStoreConfiguration {

    private static final String KEY_STORE = "keystore.p12";
    private static final String KEY_STORE_TYPE = "PKCS12";
    private static final String KEY_STORE_PASSWORD = "password";
    
    @Bean
    public KeyStore keyStore() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE_TYPE);
        keyStore.load(new ClassPathResource(KEY_STORE).getInputStream(), KEY_STORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        
        return keyStore;
    }
}
```